# Create, redirect... calls using AsterNET.ARI

Tags: .net, asterisk, freepbx, asterisk-ari, asternet

I have installed AsteriskNOW distribution with freePBX. I'm trying to implement autodialer to our existing software. I am monitoring calls wihtout any problems. Only thing that works is to hang up call. When i try to originate, redirect, hold or make similar action i get response from asterisk: **Channel not in Stasis application.**

```cs
var x = client.Channels.Originate("SIP/447", extension: "SIP/446", timeout: 30);
client.Channels.Ring(x.Id);
```

Comment: "Implement autodialler" without skill is fast path to loose money. Use vicidial or other opensource already EXISTING core. For use ARI you first have move channel to Statis app.

Comment: @arheops yes i'm looking into these solutions, but i am trying to implement very simple dallier, it would be better to have my solution... How do i move channel to Stasis app? Thanks for reply

Comment: There are no "simpler dialler". You have go Statis using dialplan.

Comment: @arheops okay thanks for reply... I will use other solutions

Comment: @arheops I'll still need one operation to do by my service, that is redirecting calls. When i try to redirect i get again **Channel not in Stasis application**. Can you tell how to fix this? or some link to documentation. I can't find solution to this. Thank you              `if (channel.State == "Up")
                client.Channels.Redirect(channel.Id, "SIP/447");`

Comment: You need put channel in Statis by dialplan first.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to originate call using Channel.Originate method as

```
var newChannel = ActionClient.Channels.Originate(endpoint, extension, context, priority, null, AppName, null, callerId, timeout, variables, channelId, otherChannelId, originator);
```

***newChannel.Id*** is the ***Channel_id*** which is created due to the above method.
Now you have to Redirect the call using 
`public void Redirect(string channelId, string endpoint)`
where channelId is your current channel and endpoint is like `"endpoint:SIP/703"`

Try this.. Good luck!!